# Show wifi selection box on iOS

Tags: c++, iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

I'm sure this is simple and covered before, but I'm clearly not looking for the right thing. When you open some apps, like Safari, iOS pops up a box asking you to select a wifi connection if you're not on wifi. I just want to do that.

Answer (score 0):

It should pop up if you set the [UIRequiresPersistentWifi](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html) key, **and** the user has Wifi enabled globally.